# Selector for all a tag descendants

Tags: css, css-selectors

Sorry if this sounds pretty basic to those who follow the css tag.

The webpage in question has multiple sections:

```
<section id="top"> ; <section id="tab-banner">
```

Within these sections there is much html with many levels of nesting.

I just want to say grab all `<a>` tags that are descendants of each section. E.g.

```css
#tab-banner a { /* css here */ }
```

How do I say grab all elements of a certain type (a) that are descendents of elements with specific IDs?

Comment: `#tab-banner a {css here}` is fine if you want just direct childrens use `#tab-banner > a {css here}`

Comment: @Danko can you clarify. To select all anchor tags that are children, grandchildren and great grandchildren of #tab-banner I'd use #tab-banner > a?

Comment: Nop if you want all `a` tags inside that id element the selector you post must work. Just if you want first level childrens use >

Comment: @Danko hmm. I wonder if I'm doing something else wrong, will investigate. You're saying that #tab-banner a should select ALL a tags within #tab-banner

Comment: Yep mate maybe is some problem with specificity. Can be other selector changing a elements inside the section or somw with `!important` If you can share us your url or fiddle

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For all descendants, use:

```
#tab-banner *
```

For direct descendants, use:

```
#tab-banner > *
```

#### Edit:

As the op changed/clarified the question:

To find all descendants of a specific type, just use that type instead of `*`. Example:

```
#tab-banner a
```

So, what you are trying is correct. If the style doesn't apply to the elements that you expect, then those elements are actually not descendants of that section, or you have another rule that takes prescedence.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it looks like the question was missing an important detail due to formatting issues at the time you answered, and the downvoter might have not taken that into account (or they felt downvoting alone was sufficient to notify you). The question seems to be looking for descendants of type `a` only.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might need the Universal selector, but I'd suggest you were more specific in how you attach your css

`#tab-banner * {css here}`


the star selector will append the styles to all the decendants but this isn't best practice as it has performance effects

[Universal_selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

for more help checkout this helpful article [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: Links very useful

Answer (score -1):

Have a try with the [Direct Child Selector](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors) :

```
#tab-banner > a { ... }
```

Comment: The question was about all a descendants.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of the question if it do not implicitly require a "direct" descendant selector...