# Changing line spacing between Bandsintown events

Tags: html, css, widget, spacing

I am using the Bandsintown widget for one of my own sites (Not Wordpress, etc.) and can't figure out how to increase the line spacing between events. Is it even possible? Too keep inline with the overall formatting of the site, I'd like there to be a bit more space between each. Thanks

```
.bit-events a {
  color: #39B082;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.bit-events th,
.bit-events td {
  padding: 0!important;
  font-family: "font_1";
}
#bit-events th.bit-date {
  width: 100px;
}
#bit-events th.bit-date,
#bit-events th.bit-venue,
#bit-events th.bit-location,
#bit-events th.bit-tickets {
  color: #39B082;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 20px;
}
#bit-events td.bit-description-links,
#bit-events th.bit-description-links,
#bit-events {
  color: #121212;
}
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please do take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you.

Comment: I've added line-spacing and padding to every id. Nothing.

Comment: I'm looking for line spacing, or spacing, in general, berween fhe different dates displayed via the Bandsintown wiget.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to add a relative line-height to your css:
[CSS - Line Spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845433/css-line-spacing)

```
#bit-events * {
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```

You can use `>` for direct descendants, `*` for all descendants of your container, or specify them individually https://stackoverflow.com/a/21410191/4541045

Otherwise, a `border-width` may be what you're looking for.
Here's an example of its usage http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp

---

To find out the value to change and to edit a live copy, you can play with a browser's inspector tool.

[image: Inspection tool example]

Normally this is accessible through some menu, and may be available when right-clicking in a webpage

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector
- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: but I need it just for the Bandsintownwidget, not the rest of the page.

Comment: You should be able to apply the `line-height` property to all descendants of a container or a specific subset by specifying them the same way you do in your code. I've updated my answer with a better example.

Comment: this worked, thank you. Do you happen to know how to alter/change the appearance of the "RSVP" button?

Comment: Excellent, and anytime! It looks like you probably want to reference `#bit-events td .bit-uiButton` to get the RSVP button. I've updated my answer with some more information on how to use an Inspector to get this value. If this or another answer on SO solves a question you ask, please do mark it as the answer.